# How to correctly bind C++ clone pattern with pybind11?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, clone, pybind11

I'm attempting to wrap a C++ class implementing the clone pattern with pybind11. I've been following the documentation provided (see https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/classes.html) but whenever I try to compile the code below, the compiler throws an error:

```
pybind11\include\pybind11\cast.h(1031,12): error C2672: 'cast_op': no matching overloaded function found [...]
pybind11\include\pybind11\cast.h(1105): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'T pybind11::cast<T,0>(const pybind11::handle &)' being compiled [...]
with
[
   T=std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>
]
pybind11\include\pybind11\cast.h(1168): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>> pybind11::cast<T>(pybind11::object &&)' being compiled [...]
with
[
   T=std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<Base>>
]
```

Code:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

#include <memory>

class Base
{
public:
    Base()
    {
    }

    virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> Clone() const
    {
        return std::make_unique<Base>(*this);
    }
};

class PyBase : public Base
{
public:
    using Base::Base;

    virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> Clone() const
    {
        PYBIND11_OVERRIDE_NAME(std::unique_ptr<Base>, Base, "clone", Clone);
    }
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, module)
{
    pybind11::class_<Base, PyBase>(module, "Base")
        .def(pybind11::init<>())
        .def("clone", &Base::Clone);
}
```

How do I correctly bind this code with pybind11?

Comment: This looks like a pybind11 problem to me, because replacing unique_ptr with shared_ptr or with a naked pointer works. I would file a bug.

Comment: There are many open issues on Pybind11 regarding what you, which is basically transfer of ownership from Python to C++, e.g., https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/1132 It's kind of complicated because it's pretty easy to lose control on what side or the other when doing so.